# Is real analysis necessary for statisticians?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, careers

I'm almost finishing the undergraduate course in Statistics. Is it worth take a course in Real Analysis if I don't intend to do the master's degree? This will help me in something in the labor market ?

Comment: 1. You mean "intend" not "pretend" right? 2. It really depends on the labour market you are targeting. Market research? Probably not. Econometrics? Financial Mathematics down the road? Maybe. 3. As you are finishing your degree I do not see much difference any answer will make anyway. If you can take the course still though, take it. It is a topic that is easier acquire in class than with self-study because it requires a somewhat high level of discipline/rigour that is hard for one to get on his own. (This is a comment, not an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not plan on grad school then real analysis will not provide any direct use, but the proof skills gained could be useful in general.